# Can't see the vertices of joined objects

Tags: mesh, vertices

I created the body of the character, the hands and feet separately, then i joined them and manually merged the vertices. Everything was perfect.

The hands and feet still are part of the body mesh and follow the armature and rig great, but I went to edit some verts while weight painting and can't see the vertices on the hands and feet.

I can select faces and edges but can't move them. If I hide the rest of the body and un-hide it, the hands and feet show verts again, until i change to any other interface mode. Then they revert back to not visible again.

I have separated the hands and feet and re-joined them and it works, until i change interface modes again.

I don't know exactly what I did nor do I know how to fix it. Materials and textures still apply same as to the rest of the body too.

I think i merged the hands and feet while the body, hands and feet all had mirror modifier on, but I do not have any duplicate meshes. Now after messing with it, I somehow have one vert on the hand that does not seem to be manipulated by the armature/rig. And I can't seem to fix that issue as well, as i think it is associated with my main issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: overlapping surfaces and one of them (the hand) has wireframe viewport display?

Comment: thank you. not sure how to fix that, but i will mess around with it. sorry but i am totally new to computer art/graphics, i have only drawn with paper, so this is another beast entirely.

Comment: ok, but never mind... the mesh seems to have a very good topology. If you want to, you can upload the blend file so that people here can have a closer look. Please use this link to do it: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Please use proper punctuation to make the text more readable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wall_of_text

Comment: i have been working really hard on this project as it is my first one really. thank you for the fast reply and the encouragement. i will send the file.

Comment: How exactly do i upload the file?

Comment: use the link I've indicated. Check the agreement boxes, add a link to the question and drop your file where indicated. Once done click upload. And when upload is finishes get the obtained link and past it here.

Comment: I uploaded the file but it stopped at the end and isn't producing confirmation link/number.

Comment: I deleted the hands and feet and appended them back in from an earlier saved version, and I edited vertices and went in and out of edit mode. Everything was working great until I weight painted, then they went right back to the issue. I also applied the transforms.